# trying to stop textarea from growing after 300px and then destroying autogrow textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am Trying to stop a textarea with autogrow.js from growing after 300px height and then destroying autogrow textarea so that it has scrollbars, although the code I have used to do this is working fine I can stop the textarea from growing after 300px but when that happens the textarea becomes smaller than 300px suddenly.

I need it to stop growing at 300px but still remain 300px in height, is this possible?

I am recreating the facebook messages box - the text area can grow but after a certain height it stops growing and the textarea has scrollbars and once you delete text from the textarea the scrollbars go away and the textarea can then grow again.

I have a working jsfiddle example with my problem inside it.

http://jsfiddle.net/jphillips/k2a2pwc8/2/
here is the code also

```
function scrollar() {
    elem = document.getElementById('box_area');
    if (elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight) {
        alert('has scrollbars');
        var inpbh = $("#inner_postbox").height();
        var inpbh_val = $("#box_area_height").val(inpbh);
        $("#box_area").height(inpbh_val);
        //$("#box_area").autosize();
        if ($("#box_area").hasClass("detract")) {
            var inpbh = $("#inner_postbox").height();
            var inpbh_val = $("#box_area_height").val(inpbh);
            $("#box_area").height(inpbh_val);
        }

    } else {

        $("#box_area").autosize();
        $("#box_area").attr('class', 'expand');
    }
}

$("#box_area").autosize();

$("#box_area").keyup(function() {
    if ($("#box_area").height() > 300) {
        if ($("#box_area").hasClass("expand")) {
            $("#box_area").trigger('autosize.destroy');
            $("#box_area").attr('class', 'detract');
        }
    } else {
        $("#box_area").autogrow();
        $("#box_area").attr('class', 'expand');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#box_area").addClass('expanded');
```

just add this piece of code to the keyup function

```
$("#box_area").keyup(function() {
    if ($("#box_area").height() > 300) {
        if ($("#box_area").hasClass("expand")) {
            $("#box_area").trigger('autosize.destroy');
            $("#box_area").attr('class', 'detract');
            $("#box_area").addClass('expanded');
        }
    } else {
        $("#box_area").autogrow();
        $("#box_area").attr('class', 'expand');
    }
});

<style>
.expanded{height:300px; overflow-x:auto}
</style>
```

Comment: that works perfectly, but it does not shrink now when you remove text

Comment: when do you want to shrink the box, is it when you clear all the text?

Comment: when you clear the text so that there are no scrollbars on the textarea

Answer (score 1):

```
var minHeight = 50;
var maxHeight = 200;

$('textarea').on('input' , function(){

  var clone = $(this).clone();
  clone.attr('rows' , 1);
  clone.css('height' , 'none');
  clone.css('position' , 'absolute');
  clone.css('visibility' , 'visible');
  clone.val($(this).val());
  $(this).after(clone);

  var rowsCount = (clone[0].scrollHeight-2*parseFloat(clone.css('padding')))/clone.height();

  var textHeight = rowsCount*parseFloat($(this).css('font-size'));

  textHeight = textHeight > minHeight && textHeight < maxHeight ? textHeight : textHeight >= maxHeight ? maxHeight : minHeight;


  $(this).attr('rows', Math.round(textHeight / parseFloat($(this).css('font-size'))))
  $(this).css('height' , 'none');

  clone.remove();
})

$('textarea').attr('rows', Math.round(minHeight / parseFloat($('textarea').css('font-size'))))
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yann86/5zrw3zrb/5/